# image is not upload using MultipartEntity

Tags: android

I want to upload single image using MultipartEntity . I have try below code.

But image is not upload. I dont get any error . I have added enough library for that

```
  try {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                    "http://192.168.1.6/uploadimg.php");
            httpClient.getParams().setParameter(
                    CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            File f = null;
            FileBody fo = null;

            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            // code for send image using post method
            f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/a.png");
            fo = new FileBody(f);
            reqEntity.addPart("uploaded", fo);

            Log.i("uploaded", "image added Parameter added");

            postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(

            response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

            String sResponse;

            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                s = s.append(sResponse);

            }
            Log.v("Upload photo", "Response" + s);

            // return getUploadResponce(s.toString());
            // Log.i("Response ", );

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

PHP file

```
<?php

$file = $_FILES['uploaded']

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['uploaded']['name']);

            ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem  there is problem in getting path of image, change single of line code;

Use:

```
String xtStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/a.png";
 f = new File(xtStorageDirectory);
```

Instead:

```
f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/a.png");
```

And make sure you have given permission of accessing [external storage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) in manifest file, below one.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I have given only internet permission

Comment: @NiravRanpara I update my answer, to access from sdcard you have to give appropriate permission.

Comment: print String `xtStorageDirectory` and even check what you are getting in this log `Log.v("Upload photo", "Response" + s);`